# Why does the data return undefined in a for loop even in a .then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, call

Currently trying to figure out why dataset[i]["stationId"] is coming back as undefined.
I have tried to use the data I set as well but it would return undefined as well. However, If I console log something like dataset[0]["stationId"] , I'd be able to get something back but just not in a for loop. What I'm trying to do is to restructure the data I receive from the call.

Thanks in advance for answering !

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    let arr= []
    var i;

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEvents = () => {
                fetch(`http://${ip.trim()}:${port}/events/station`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    setData(json);
                    console.log(data)
                })
                .then(dataset =>{
                    if(arr.length === 0){
                                arr[0] = {stationId : dataset[0]["stationId"], event_type: dataset[0]["event_type"], duration: [dataset[0]["duration"]]}
                    }

                    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
                        for(i=0; i<dataset.length; i++){
                            // if station id is not the same 
                                if(arr[i]["stationId"] !== dataset[i]["stationId"]){
                                    arr.push(dataset[i])
                                }
                                else if(arr[i]["event_type"] === dataset[i]["event_type"]){
                                    arr[i]["duration"].push(dataset[i]["duration"])
                                }
                                else{
                                    arr[i]["event_type"] = dataset[i]["event_type"]
                                    arr[i]["duration"] = [dataset[i]["duration"]]
                                }

                        }
                    }

                    
                })
                .catch(
                    err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                );
        };

        fetchEvents();

    }, []);
```

Comment: You are using `i` in both `for` loops, so you add twice to `i` every loop. That's why goes wrong.

Comment: Klassiek , WELL spotted ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you two `for` loops use the same counter. After every pass through the inner `for` loop, the `i` gets increased, and then in the outer `for` loop it gets increased again. At some point the `i` will have increased to much and `dataset[i]` will be undefined.

Putting the inner `for` loop in a function would have countered this problem, like do:

```
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = check(dataset, arr[i]);
}

function check(dataset, arri){
    for(var i=0; i<dataset.length; i++){
        // if station id is not the same 
            if(arri["stationId"] !== dataset[i]["stationId"]){
                arri.push(dataset[i])
            }
            else if(arri["event_type"] === dataset[i]["event_type"]){
                arri["duration"].push(dataset[i]["duration"])
            }
            else{
                arri["event_type"] = dataset[i]["event_type"]
                arri["duration"] = [dataset[i]["duration"]]
            }

    }
    return arri
}
```

But, there is another problem, the `push` method. Say, the `arr[i]` is as follows:

```
arr[i]  === {stationId : 1, event_type: "a_type", duration: [1,2,3]}
```

Then doing `arr[i].push(dataset[i])` will not work. The `push` method is for `Array`s. You are trying to push something on an `Object`. `Object`s do not have a `push` method...

Comment: Thanks Klassiek. I realised everything was wrong after you posted the first comment and fixed all.